# Native Context not available using Leapmotion AS3 ANE file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, leap-motion

I´m getting this error while trying to compile a Flashdevelop AIR project:

```
Native Context not available. The Config class is only available in Adobe AIR.
```

My setup:

- Using Starling.
- Using the ANE file from https://github.com/logotype/LeapMotionAS3
- Using Flex SDK 4.6.0/AIR 3.8 in Flashdevelop 4.4.4 RTM
- Extended Desktop profile is on.

The error fires up when I try to use the controller.config() or screen.* as in:

```
if(leap.config().setFloat("Gesture.Swipe.MinLength", 200.0) && leap.config().setFloat("Gesture.Swipe.MinVelocity", 500)) leap.config().save();
```

My onConnect();

```
private function alConectar(event:LeapEvent):void{
            trace("conectado");


            leap.enableGesture(Gesture.TYPE_SWIPE);
            leap.enableGesture(Gesture.TYPE_SCREEN_TAP);
            if(leap.config().setFloat("Gesture.Swipe.MinLength", 200.0) && leap.config().setFloat("Gesture.Swipe.MinVelocity", 500)) leap.config().save();
            if(leap.config().setFloat("Gesture.ScreenTap.MinForwardVelocity", 30.0) && leap.config().setFloat("Gesture.ScreenTap.HistorySeconds", .5) && leap.config().setFloat("Gesture.ScreenTap.MinDistance", 1.0)) leap.config().save();
            //etc...

        }
```

The full output:

```
Running process: C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "C:\Users\CASA\Documents\00_INTERACTIVE\LEAP\Leap_AirAS3Proj\Leap_AirAS3Proj.as3proj" -ipc 8b4c615f-60f6-46ac-aec0-093781073835 -version "3.8.0" -compiler "C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\ascsdk" -library "C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Library"
Building Leap_AirAS3Proj
mxmlc-cli -load-config="C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\ascsdk/frameworks/air-config.xml" -load-config+=obj\Leap_AirAS3ProjConfig.xml -debug=true -inline=true +configname=air -swf-version=21 -o obj\Leap_AirAS3Proj635190875306772137
Running java as: java.exe
Loading configuration: C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\ascsdk\frameworks\air-config.xml
Loading configuration: C:\Users\CASA\Documents\00_INTERACTIVE\LEAP\Leap_AirAS3Proj\obj\Leap_AirAS3ProjConfig.xml

206311 bytes written to C:\Users\CASA\Documents\00_INTERACTIVE\LEAP\Leap_AirAS3Proj\obj\Leap_AirAS3Proj635190875306772137 in 6.156 seconds
Build succeeded
Done(0)
[Starting debug session with FDB]
[Starling] Initialization complete.
[Starling] Display Driver: DirectX9 (Baseline Constrained)
init
conectado
[Fault] exception, information=Error: Native Context not available. The Config class is only available in Adobe AIR.
```

Already change the bat/SetupSDK to: set FLEX_SDK=C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\ascsdk to reflect the SDK (Thanks to Philippe from Flashdevelop).

Any help is welcome.
Regards!

Comment: Did you try to compile with Flash Pro or Flash Builder?

Comment: I don´t have Flash Builder. Let me try with Flash CS6.

Comment: could you add if there is any other trace logs. it cant find controller.context(leap.context) but why ? maybe you should call these methods when handling init or connect

Comment: I update the post with the complete output and the onConnect() function. Regards!

Comment: I compile with FB 4.7 and it works.
Bad ANE installation I suppose.